# Long Field Name in ArcGIS Online Hosted Table Strips Data

Tags: arcgis-online, table, fields-attributes, hosting

I've encountered an issue when uploading a CSV to ArcGIS Online as a hosted table where if the field name exceeds X number of characters (I have not discovered this number yet), all data in that field is stripped out of the table.

I have managed to work around this by shortening field names before the upload process, but I would like to understand this issue better. Is this a known limitation of ArcGIS Online, or is this a new bug?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this--maximum character limit in a field in SQL is 31 characters, which is why ArcGIS Online *very* silently balks at any field with more than 31 characters in its name. Wish there was error handling for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with some columns inside a SQL Server database. I tend to use QGIS instead, because there isn't really another workaround strategy.